# VBA open the folder before

Tags: vba, excel

I want to open the folder before the current Directory each time. I tried "..\"  but it didn't work, can you help me with that N

```
ThecurrentDirectory= fso.GetParentFolderName(objFile)
Set myWorkBook = myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open( ThecurrentDirectory & "\..\CLIENTS.xlsx" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pack the ThecurrentDirectory in another fso.GetParentFolderName.

```
ThecurrentDirectory= fso.GetParentFolderName(objFile)
Set myWorkBook = myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open( fso.GetParentFolderName(ThecurrentDirectory) & "\CLIENTS.xlsx" )
```

Answer (score 1):

If objFile is a file object then you can chain it's ParentFolder property together multiple times to get the disred result:

```
Dim fso, f
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set objFile = fso.GetFile("C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverfow\test.xlsm")
```

Output:

- objFile.ParentFolder.ParentFolder = C:\Users\best buy\Downloads